# In a stringified array is it possible to differentiate between quotes that were in a string and those that surrounded the string itself?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Some Context:

• I'm still learning to code atm (started less than a year ago)

• I'm mostly self taught at that since I think my computer science class feels
too slow.

• The website I'm learning on is code.org, specifically in the "game lab"

• The site's coding environments only use ES5 because they don't want to
update them to ES6 or something like that

• In class we're making function libraries and while not required, I want
mine to be "highly usable," for lack of a better term, while also being
reasonably short (prefer not to automate things if I can get them done
quicker somehow, but that's just personal preference).

So now for where the actual question comes in: in a stringified array, is it possible to differentiate between a quotation mark that was inside a string and a quotation mark that actually denotes a string? Because I noticed something confusing with the output of JSON.parse(JSON.stringify()) on code.org, specifically, if you write something like,

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(['hi","hi']))
```

the output will be `["hi","hi"]` which looks just like an array containing two strings (on code.org it doesn't show the \'s), but still contains just one, which is fine unless you're using a regular expression to detect whether or not a match is within a string (if every quotation mark after the match has a "partner"), which is what I'm doing in 4 different functions. One flattens a list (since ES5 doesn't have Array.prototype.flat()), one removes all instances of the arguments from a list, one removes all instances of specified operand types, and one replaces all instances of an argument with the one that follows it.

Now I know the odds of a string containing an odd number of quotation marks (whether single or double) is likely extremely low, but it still bothers me that not having a way to differentiate between quotes formerly within a string and quotes which formerly denoted a string (in an array after it's been stringified) as these functions otherwise function exactly as intended. The regular expression I'm using to determine if there's an even number of quotes left in the stringified array is `/(?=[^"]*(?:(?:"[^"]*){2})*$)/` where you put the match before the lookahead assertion and anything you absolutely want to follow before the first `[^"]*`.

To highlight the actual issue I'm trying to solve, this is my flatten function (since it's the shortest of the 4), and yeah, yeah, I know "eval bad" but it's extremely convenient to use here since it shortens the actual modification into a single line, and I highly doubt anyone's actually going to find a way to abuse it given its implementation ("this" needs to be an array for splice to work, so if I'm not mistaken, there isn't really a way to abuse it, but tell me if I'm wrong, since I probably am).

```
Array.prototype.flatten = function() {
  eval(('this.splice(0,this.length,' + JSON.stringify(this).replace(/[\[\]](?=[^"]*(?:(?:"[^"]*){2})*$)/g, '') + ')').replace(/,(?=((,[^"]*(?:(?:"[^"]*){2})*)*.$))/g, ''));
  return this;
};
```

This works really well outside of the previously specified conditions, but if I were to call it with something like `[1,'"']` it'd find 3 quotation marks after the \[ and wouldn't be able to remove it but would be able to remove the \], thus when eval actually gets to .splice(), it would look like `eval('this.splice(0,this.length,[1,"\"")')` causing the error `Unexpected token ')'` to be thrown

Any help on this is appreciated, even if it's just telling me it isn't possible, thanks for reading my ramblings.

TL;DR: in a stringified array is it possible to differentiate between " and \" (string wrapping quotes of strings within a stringified array and quotes within a string within a stringified array) in a regular expression or any other method using only the tools available in ES5 (site I'm learning on doesn't want to update their project environments  for whatever reason)

Comment: You might want to look at the documentation for [`.flat()` alternatives](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat#alternatives)

Comment: What is the root of the mismatched quotes to begin with? Using `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))` should never return erroneous results if the object is correct to start with. Your example with `['hi","hi']` is an array with one string and does not return `["hi","hi"]` as you suggest it returns `["hi\",\"hi"]` which maintains it as an array with a single string element with escaped inner quotes

Comment: I was saying the quotes appear the same on code.org, they only have \" internally, not when the regular expression runs, meaning that it doesn't have a way to differentiate between " and \", which in turn means that the quote matching script in the regular expressions can be "tricked" thinking a match is inside a string when it's actually outside and visa versa

Comment: There is a whole lot of text in question....too much to be honest, and no TL;DR version. Are you trying to solve  a real or a ***perceived*** problem?

Comment: It's real in the sense that it allows for the functions to break when they otherwise shouldn't, but I can't be certain that it's replicable outside of code.org since it runs on a previous version of ES. I'll try and add a more to the point explanation to the post

Comment: @pilchard can't seem to get the .flat() alternatives shown working on the website since arrow functions were introduced in ES6, and I can't figure out how to format the examples as normal functions without creating an error, so I'm assuming there's differences I'm not picking up on when attempting to convert

Comment: @charlietfl srry, I've used the site before but never really interacted with it, just noticed I can @ people

Comment: The version of ES 5 vs 6 shouldn't affect using JSON methods or regex or  **cause** irregular quote issues. Still feels like to me you are chasing an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: @charlietfl I mean, I guess any alternative to the .flat() function that works in ES5 would negate the need to answer my original question, so yes, I guess I am chasing an XY problem, but I also don't want to feel like I just stole code and passed it off as my own (I mean, I'm submitting this for an assignment), which is why I'm looking to improve the answer to the problem of ES5 not having a dedicated .flat() function that I came up with (unless it does and I'm just dumb or just can't access it for whatever reason) rather than just asking for someone else's solution to the problem as a whole

Comment: @charlietfl after reading more on XY problems, I suppose I should also add that I'm continuing to pursue this solution is because the function libraries on the website have a limited amount of overall text they can contain for whatever reason, so I prefer to keep my functions as short as possible and I like to try to reduce runtime (though that's just preference, if there's no other solution other than to use an older version that doesn't use RegExp, which both took longer to run and was longer). Knowing if it's impossible to differentiate between " and \" would also answer my question though

Comment: I'm lost. Title and most of the discussion is about string quotes not about flat(). No there is no such direct method in ES5 but finding alternatives is not difficult. I can't see any correlation whatsoever between using a flat() alternative and the quote issue though

Comment: @charlietfl sorry, yeah, I know it's not that difficult to automate, but I like my code to run quickly and also be short, I really should've said that was a preference at the beginning, my bad

Comment: @charlietfl also, idk why but I forgot that the actual problem (not being able to differentiate between quotes within a string \" and quotes designating a string ") applied to 3 other functions of mine, so I didn't mean to say that the problem was ES5's lack of a .flat() function, sorry about that as well

Comment: I would encourage you to thoroughly read [ask] and keep question(s) on a single track. Mixing flat alternatives and string quote issues is really unproductive and has this whole thing diverging in too many directions none of which are likely helping you so far

Comment: @charlietfl alright, thanks, and sorry I'm a bit scatterbrained, adhd lol

Comment: @charlietfl cleaned it up a lot, clarified certain things more and fixed a lot of continuity errors I found that I hadn't noticed while writing, I think it reads a lot clearer now, but let me know if you read it over and still find it confusing hard to follow, thanks for being patient with me

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up finding a way to do this, for whatever reason (either I didn't notice last night because I was tired or it legitimately changed overnight, though likely the former) I can now see the " when viewing the value of the the stringified array, and lo and behold modifying the regular expression so that it ignored instances of " resolved the issue.
New regular expression for quotation mark pair matching now reads:

```
// old even number of quotation marks after match check
/(?=[^"]*(?:(?:"[^"]*){2})*$)/
// new even number of quotation marks after match check
/(?=(\\"|[^"])*(?:(?:(?<!\\)"(\\"|[^"])*){2})*$)/
// (only real difference is that it accounts for the \)
```

Sorry for anyone who may have misunderstood the question due to how all over the place it was, I'm aware that I tend to end up writing a lot more than is necessary and it often leads to tangents that muddle my view of what I was initially asking, which in turn makes the point I'm actually trying to get across even harder to grasp at. Thanks to those who still tried to help me regardless of how much of a mess of a first question this was.